# Deploy Spring Cloud Data Flow 2.6.0 to Openshift

Tags: openshift, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to deploy SCDF 2.6.0 to Openshift.
I can verify DB schema is updated successfully, but seems like the Tomcat failed to start with below error and I have no idea what is going on.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: standardService.connector.startFailed
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
```

**Steps reproduce**

Use MariaDB, then import the *.yaml in below sequence

1. server-roles.yaml
2. server-rolebinding.yaml
3. service-account.yaml
4. server-config.yaml (make sure to change the DB connection here )
5. server-svc.yaml
6. server-deployment.yaml

I uploaded all the yml and full log file in my repo :
https://github.com/gry77/app-issue-repo/tree/master/Openshift-SCDF-issue/k8s-config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this error gone after I changed the server port from 80 to something else.

so just change the server.port in the environment to other then 80

Answer (score 0):

OpenShift will not allow you to run containers as privileged by default, so you'll need to specifically allow that using a `SecurityContextConstraint`. There is a good documentation on how to get SCDF to run on OpenShift here: https://donovanmuller.blog/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-openshift/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_creating_and_configuring_service_accounts

Basically, you'll need to add the `anyuid` SCC to the ServiceAccount running the Pods:

```
oc adm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid system:serviceaccount:scdf:scdf
```